# How to reshape Numpy array with padded 0's

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a Numpy array that looks like

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

and I want to reshape it to an array

```
array([[5, 0, 0, 6],
       [0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 0],
       [7, 0, 0, 8]])
```

More specifically, I'm trying to reshape a 2D numpy array to get a 3D Numpy array to go from

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       ...
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96]])
```

to a numpy array that looks like

```
array([[[ 5,  0,  0,  6],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  0],
        [ 0,  3,  4,  0],
        [ 7,  0,  0,  8]],

       [[13,  0,  0, 14],
        [ 0,  9, 10,  0],
        [ 0, 11, 12,  0],
        [15,  0,  0, 16]],
       ...
       [[93,  0,  0, 94],
        [ 0, 89, 90,  0],
        [ 0, 91, 92,  0],
        [95,  0,  0, 96]]])
```

Is there an efficient way to do this using numpy functionality, particularly vectorized?

Comment: Would the input always have 8 elements? For 2D, 8 elements in each row?

Comment: Yeah, input has a fixed number of elements. For 2D, this is 8 elements per row (not per column). For 2D, I want to be able to do this for any number of rows though

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Yep, it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make use of `slicing` -

```
def expand(a): # a is 2D array      
    out = np.zeros((len(a),4,4),dtype=a.dtype)
    out[:,1:3,1:3] = a[:,:4].reshape(-1,2,2)
    out[:,::3,::3] = a[:,4:].reshape(-1,2,2)
    return out
```

The benefit is memory and hence perf. efficiency, as only the output would occupy memory space. The steps involved work with views thanks to the slicing on the input and output.

Sample run -

2D input :

```
In [223]: a
Out[223]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]])

In [224]: expand(a)
Out[224]: 
array([[[ 5,  0,  0,  6],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  0],
        [ 0,  3,  4,  0],
        [ 7,  0,  0,  8]],

       [[13,  0,  0, 14],
        [ 0,  9, 10,  0],
        [ 0, 11, 12,  0],
        [15,  0,  0, 16]]])
```

1D input (feed in 2D extended input with `None`) :

```
In [225]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

In [226]: expand(a[None])
Out[226]: 
array([[[5, 0, 0, 6],
        [0, 1, 2, 0],
        [0, 3, 4, 0],
        [7, 0, 0, 8]]])
```